# Setting div to position fixed and 100vh causes 'jump' on mobile and tablet

Tags: mobile, fixed, tablet

I am building a website with Webflow and encountered an issue that seems to be quite common. My Hero section is supposed to be 100vh and 100vw on all screens. And I also want it to set to position fixed, so that the content below it slides over it when the user scrolls down. On Desktop this all works fine but on Tablet and Mobile I have the issue with the browser's search / address bar.

Basically, once you scroll and the search/address bar minimizes itself, the screen kind off 'jumps' to again show the website in 100vh.

I read a lot about this but most solutions are from a few years ago and don't seem to work anymore.

Is there any code to fix this or should I just not use fixed positioning on mobile screens?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you already solved your issue, I found out that the simpliest way to address this problem is to use:

```
height:100%
```

instead of using 100vh. With fixed position it works well to me and the address bar does not overlay anymore.

You need to have a % height on body too for this to work!